# Properly data management between components

Tags: reactjs

I have two components (Parent and Child). Parent component renders a lot of child components(Card) and the general structure of the page. Every Card has a unique id.

Every Card has a checkbox and initial state of the checkbox should be false. I want to share the status of checkbox with Parent component dynamically. So basically when I checked or unchecked the checkbox for a Card, **I want to know which card is checked or unchecked in the parent component.**

Parent

```
this.state = {
        isChecked: false // I shouldn't set false?
    }

onChange = (val) => {
    this.setState({isChecked : val})
}

return results.map(card => {
        return <Card isChecked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.onChange}/>
    })
```

Card (Child)

```
this.state = {
        isChecked: false // I shouldn't set false?
    }

handleOnChange = () => {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked})
    this.props.onChange(this.state.isChecked);
}

<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => {this.handleOnChange()}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index value as props and then you will receive the id in child component when you check at that time pass the index as second parameter so in parent component in onChange function you will receive the checked input index.
Parent

```
this.state = {
        isChecked: false // I shouldn't set false?
    }

onChange = (val,index) => {
    this.setState({isChecked : val})
}

return results.map((card,index) => {
        return <Card isChecked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.onChange} 
               checkboxId={index} />
    })
```

Card (Child)

```
handleOnChange = () => {
   this.props.onChange(!this.props.isChecked,this.props.checkboxId);
}

<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => {this.handleOnChange()}} />
```

Comment: In this case if I check the card first time the value will be false!

Comment: In your child component you are not using state of isChecked value right so no need to define isChecked in state and updating it directly you can pass props values of isChecked by adding not (!) symbol  in font of it

Answer (score 0):

`You don't need to pass isChecked: false`, this is the working solution.

```js
// Parent component
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cardArray: [],
    results: [1, 2, 4, 5]
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let updatedArray = [];
    this.state.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      let checkboxObj = { index: "", isChecked: false };
      checkboxObj.index = index;
      updatedArray.push(checkboxObj);
    });
    this.setState({ cardArray: updatedArray });
  }
  onChange = (value, index) => {
    let updatedArray = this.state.cardArray;
    updatedArray.forEach(result => {
      if (result.index === index) result.isChecked = value;
    });
    console.log(updatedArray);
    this.setState({ cardArray: updatedArray });
  };

  render() {
    let results = this.state.results;
    return results.map((card, index) => {
      return (
        <Card
          index={index}
          isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
          onChange={value => this.onChange(value, index)}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}

//Child component

class Card extends React.Component {

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.checked);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label>{this.props.index}</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={event => {
            this.handleOnChange(event);
          }}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. First of all, I don't have cardArray in my  parent's state and I will never have.  This way doesn't make sense for me. Thank you.

Comment: @reeeact in cardArray we will update all child checkbox state, and you mentioned in question Your words:- `I want to share the status of checkbox with Parent component dynamically. So basically when I checked or unchecked the checkbox for a Card, I want to know which card is checked or unchecked in the parent component.`

Answer (score 0):

Since each Card is independent, each should have its own `isChecked` property.

In order for you to be aware of which Card is checked and which isn't, you must maintain the state of the cards in the Parent Component itself **and** you should also pass down the `onChange` method over to the Child so that whenever a card is checked or unchecked, the Parent's state can change.

Parent Component:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    results: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  };

  // Recursively adding isChecked property on each Card
  componentDidMount() {
    const updatedResults = this.state.results.map(card => {
      card["isChecked"] = false;
      return card;
    })
    this.setState({
      results: updatedResults
    })
  }

      onChange = id => {
        let newResults = this.state.results.map(card => {
              if (card.id === id) {
                 card.isChecked = !card.isChecked;
          }
          return card;
        });
        this.setState({
          results: newResults
        });
      };

  render() {
    const cards = this.state.results.map(card => {
      return <Card card={card} onChange={id => this.onChange(id)} />;
    });
    return <div>{cards}</div>;
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>Card no. {this.props.card.id}</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={e => {
            this.props.onChange(this.props.card.id); // Doesn't define it own onChange method and invokes the one passed down by the Parent.
          }}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wjwjr0z4p)

Comment: No, my results array doesn't store isChecked property.